# How do I set total number of pages in ExtJS 4 paging?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, paging

I am not sure if its possible or not but I was wondering if I could set the number of pages in paging. That is I can set page 1 of 20. (If I set my total Pages to be 20) Also when someone clicks in next page then it will return the data for page which depends on the page number but can be of any size that is I don't want to limit page size. It will be dynamic page size depending upon the page number. Mostly what I was looking is in the first when someone submits the form I can send the total number of pages and when they click the next it will show all the data for that page. I was wondering if I can send total number of pages as we sent totalProperty for total number of data rows. like below. I want to make pagesize dynamic which will be like how totalProperty= total is now. Also I would like to know if I can set total number of pages.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model: 'test_data_layout',
    pageSize: '50',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: url,
        actionMethods: {
            create : 'POST',
            read   : 'POST',
            update : 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
            },
        reader: { 
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
         }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works.
You tell it how many records in total you have and how many records you want to fit into a page and it calculates the number of pages for you. Simple.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I was looking if that was possible. I wanted a different solution for my problem. Thank you anyway.